# CSV to html with dynamic color coding

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have written the shell script below to convert csv to HTML with color coding for a single file and it's working properly.
The condition for color coding is different for different reports (csv files), so I wanted to make it dynamic instead of hard coding the condition.

This is my current code for one report:

```
cd /gk/laaz/

ipfile=$1
opfile=$2
condition=$3

awk -v cond="$condition" 'BEGIN{

FS="|"
  print "<html><body></br></br>The report .</br></br></br>"
  print "<table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1>"
}

NR==1 {
  # Header row
  print "<tr>"

  for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
    print "<td><b>"$i"</b></td>"
  }
  print "</tr>"
}

NR>1 {
  # Data rows
  print "<tr>"
  color="RED"

  for ( i = 1; i < NF; i++ ) {
color="RED"
if( $1=="180817CR0003988" ) {
    color="BLUE"
    }

   print "<td><b><FONT COLOR=\""color"\" FACE=\"verdana\" SIZE=2>"$i"</b></FONT></td>"
  }
 print "</tr>"
}
END {
  print "</table></body></html>"
}
' $ipfile >> $opfile
fi
```

In this code, I want to use the `awk` variable `cond` in the `if` statement but it's not working.

This code is working:

```
if( $1=="180817CR0003988" ) {
    color="BLUE"
    }
```

But this is not:

```
if( cond ) {
    color="BLUE"
    }
```

I launch the script with:

```
/gk/laaz/csv2html.sh sample.csv sample.html "\$1==\"180817CR0003988\""
```

Comment: What is the third parameter that you are passing to the script?

Comment: condition for report...like  if first column is equal to   $1=="180817CR0003988" then use  red color for that row.

Comment: Yes, but what is it. What is the value of `cond` when `if( cond )` is run? Please [edit[]your question and show us the command you use to launch the script, including this variable.

Comment: i run below command      
 /gk/laaz/csv2html.sh sample.csv sample.html "\$1==\"180817CR0003988\""

Comment: I would suggest you edit title question in the like of "conditionnal awk test for 100's of files"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use a variable.

awk allow for multiple input program file.

generate a temporary awk file for every case like :

for `file1.csv` generate a `temporary.awk` program (file1.awk)

```
function check() { if ( $1 == ""180817CR0003988" ) return "blue" ; else "back" }
```

for `fileX.csv`

```
function check() { if ( $9 == ""unix.stackexchange.com" ) return "grey" ; else "blue" }
```

then in call use

```
color=check() ;
```

awk being called as

```
awk -f temporary.awk -f long.awk ...
```

your awk's statement being big, I suggest putting it in a file named `long.awk` .

Answer (score 2):

Awk variables are treated as strings. You can't even [pass an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33106291/1081936), let alone a condition. But you don't need to. Instead of passing the condition, just pass the value it needs to run:

```
if( $1 == cond ) {
    color="BLUE"
}
```

Then, you launch the script with:

```
/gk/laaz/csv2html.sh sample.csv sample.html 180817CR0003988
```

Comment: Hi, but there are 100 reports and every time column would be different. Like in this case , color coding was dependent on value of column number 1. But for other reports column would be 2 or 3 or something else. So I cant hard code it with if ( $1 == cond ) {color="BLUE"} .

Comment: @gaurav_hodade then please edit your question and make that clear. In order to be able to help you, we need to know all of your requirements, we can't guess.

Comment: to add to terdon's answer strings cannot be used as statement, eg `cond=$1=="foo"` cannot be passed as as variable to trigerr ìf ( $1=="foo")` in awk.